# How to resize an image in R

Tags: r, image

Let say I have image of dimensions (1, 50, 141, 1). How can resize it to dimensions (None, 40, 110, 1) using R?

I know for imager package, but it only allows to resize width and height using:

```
resize(image, width, height)
```

Example:

```
library(imager)
img <- load.image('.../extdata/parrots.png')
dim(img)
img <- resize(img, 110, 40)

# want dim(img) <- c(110, 40, 1, None)
```

Comment: ...maybe I'm missing something, but what are the third and fourth dimensions?

Comment: I think debt and colour?

Comment: I'm a fan of using `imagemagick` directly for this: [`magick convert rose.jpg -resize 50% rose.png`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php). Perhaps not what you wanted to hear (not an "R" solution), but perhaps there's no need to introduce complexity, and if you want to automate it in R, you can use `system2(...)`.

Comment: thanks, but how to use `magick convert` to get above dimensions?

Comment: use the `magick`  in R. It's better than using the command line

Comment: I solved my problem. Thanks